# Must the Black Sky die?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders-2017

At the end of the second season of *Daredevil*,

> Elektra is resurrected to serve the Hand.

After this, she was referred to as the “Black Sky,” and possessed lethal combat abilities.

However, she was called by this name *before* her death, and she also was very dangerous in combat before she was resurrected. Further, it seemed like Nobu wasn’t terribly interested in killing her.

Was it necessary for her to die and be resurrected to attain the powers of the Black Sky? Or was this just a exigency caused by her unexpected death?